# Squirrel Powershell file is not creating the Setup.exe

Tags: c#, powershell, continuous-delivery, squirrel.windows

I have the following PowerShell script being run on my build server

```
Write-Host "Current Path  $env:Agent_BuildDirectory"
Write-Host "Build Number  $env:Build_BuildNumber"
$squirrel = "$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\packages\squirrel.windows.*\tools\Squirrel.exe"
$releaseDir = '.\Releases'
$nugetPackFile = ".\MyApp\MyApp.$env:Build_BuildNumber.nupkg"
Write-Host $squirrel
Write-Host $nugetPackFile

if((Test-Path $nugetPackFile) -and (Test-Path $squirrel)) {
    $squirrelArg1 = '--releasify=' + $nugetPackFile
    $squirrelArg2 = '--releaseDir=' + $releaseDir
    & $squirrel $squirrelArg1 $squirrelArg2 
}
```

It runs and it creates only a `nupkg` in the `.\Releases` folder.  If I run the same `--releasify` command in the Visual Studio instance on my build server agent it creates all the `setup.exe` and `Releases` file.  Why is this PowerShell script not working the same way the command being run in the NuGet PowerShell window in VS is?

Answer (score 2):

I've not played with Squirrel, so this may not work; but too much code here to just submit as a comment...

Try this:

```
Write-Host "Current Path  $env:Agent_BuildDirectory"
Write-Host "Build Number  $env:Build_BuildNumber"
$squirrel = Get-Item (Join-Path $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY "packages\squirrel.windows.*\tools\Squirrel.exe") | select -First 1 -Expand FullName
$releaseDir = '.\Releases'
$nugetPackFile = ".\MyApp\MyApp.$env:Build_BuildNumber.nupkg"
Write-Host $squirrel
Write-Host $nugetPackFile

if((Test-Path $nugetPackFile) -and (Test-Path $squirrel)) {
    $squirrelArg1 = "--releasify=`"$nugetPackFile`""
    $squirrelArg2 = "--releaseDir=`"$releaseDir`""
    & $squirrel $squirrelArg1 $squirrelArg2 
}
```

**Getting Squirrel.exe Path**

- `(Join-Path $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY "packages\squirrel.windows.*\tools\Squirrel.exe")`
   - here I use `Join-Path` to avoid any issues around whether or not the value of `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` ends in a backslash.
- `Get-Item` - I put this before that path so that it will resolve the path to a valid path (i.e. working out any matches of the asterisk/wildcard).
- `| select -First 1 -Expand FullName` I then add this to get the first path which matches the result, and to return the full file path to `squirrel.exe`

**Passing Parameters**

For the statements below, I added double quotes around the paths; sometimes this is required to clarify which argument they relate to; particularly if there are any spaces or special characters in the paths.  I also switched from using `+` to putting the variable within double quotes as this makes it simpler to concatenate the quotes within the string.  I used backticks on the quotes in the string to escape those characters.

- `` $squirrelArg1 = "--releasify=`"$nugetPackFile`"" ``
- `` $squirrelArg2 = "--releaseDir=`"$releaseDir`"" ``

Hope that helps, but sadly this is very much guesswork by me; sorry.

---

**Update**

Getting the latest version; assuming asterisk in the path `packages\squirrel.windows.*\tools\Squirrel.exe` represents the version number in the form: `Major`.`Minor`.`Build`.

```
$squirrel = Get-Item (Join-Path $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY "packages\squirrel.windows.*\tools\Squirrel.exe") | %{
    if ($_ -match '.*\\squirrel\.windows\.(?<Major>\d+)\.(?<Minor>\d+)\.(?<Build>\d+)\\tools\\Squirrel\.exe') {
        (new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property $matches)
    }
} | sort @{e={$_.Major};a=0}, @{e={$_.Minor};a=0}, @{e={$_.Build};a=0} | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty '0'
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I got caught up and then tired.  I am trying this now.  One question about the 'First' command....would it be possible to do a 'Last' command so a folder with a higher version number would be selected?

Comment: These changes appear to have accomplished the same thing on the build server as my code did.  They are an upgrade, but don't solve my problem with squirrel.

Comment: Hey @PlTaylor; sorry to hear this didn't resolve your issue.  Regarding `-Last`; absolutely that will do what you want.  i.e. `1..10 | select -Last 1` returns `10`.

Comment: would Last be able to tell the difference between version numbers like 1.20, 1.58, 2.10 for example.  Just covering my bases as I am not that familiar with powershell.

Comment: Good point; it would sort things in string order; so with the above examples all would be OK as they're the same in string & numeric order; but there could be scenarios where that doesn't work; i.e. `1, 10, 11, 2, 3` is sorted in alphanumeric order rather than numeric order.  There's probably a workaround if there's a consistent format for these strings; i.e. use a regex to pull out the version number, convert to a number, then sort it; but would require a tweak... Will take a look this evening to find out what Squirrel paths look like...

Comment: Still a lot more likely to do what I actually want than any other method :)  Just trying to line up possible causes of failures.

Comment: Updated to include logic for sorting by version number.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/issues/489)

```
Write-Host "Current Path  $env:Agent_BuildDirectory"
Write-Host "Build Number  $env:Build_BuildNumber"

$squirrel = Get-Item (Join-Path $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY "packages\squirrel.windows.*\tools\Squirrel.exe") | %{
if ($_ -match '.*\\squirrel\.windows\.(?<Major>\d+)\.(?<Minor>\d+)\.(?<Build>\d+)\\tools\\Squirrel\.exe') {
    (new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property $matches)
    }
} | sort @{e={$_.Major};a=0}, @{e={$_.Minor};a=0}, @{e={$_.Build};a=0} | select -First 1 -ExpandProperty '0'

Set-Alias Squirrel $squirrel

$releaseDir = '.\Releases'
$nugetPackFile = ".\MyApp\MyApp.$env:Build_BuildNumber.nupkg"
Write-Host $squirrel
Write-Host $nugetPackFile

if((Test-Path $nugetPackFile) -and (Test-Path $squirrel)) {
    Squirrel --releasify $nugetPackFile --releaseDir $releaseDir | Write-Output
}
```

Much thanks goes to @JohnLBevan for helping to fix up my powershell code.